Inverse of the sum of identity matrices
I want to perform the $(I+B)^{-1}$ operation with low computational complexity, where I is the identity matrix and B is an almost tridiagonal matrix. While doing this, the rank of matrix B must be 1 for the Miller method, but matrix B contains full rank. That's why the computational complexity increases. On the other hand, when I use the Thomas method, I have to ignore some elements, so the amount of error increases. Are there methods with lower computational complexity for this situation?
B matrix = enter image description here

I suppose you know the identity $(I+B)^{-1}=I-B+B^2-B^3+\cdots $, in case this is helpful.

Yes, when I tried the Taylor series expansion, $I$ saw that there was convergence. $I$ even thought that the direct result would be $\approx I-B$, but the error amount turned out to be high because the sparse elements in the $B$ matrix are much smaller than one, but the main diagonal elements contain values ​​close to one. In terms of equality, there is a situation like this; $(I+B)^{-1}=I-B(I+B)^{-1}$, $(I+B)^{-1}= I-B+B^{2}(I+B)^{-1}$, $(I+B)^{-1}= I-B+B^{2}-B^{3}(I+B)^{-1}$ goes on.

Please give a reference to the "Thomas method" you mention.

You can access the Thomas method I mentioned from the link below.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm
